# Orthogonal projection $P_{W_1}P_{W_2} = P_{W_2}P_{W_1}\iff W_1\perp W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $V$ be a vector space such that $\dim V  < \infty $ with an inner product. Let $W_1,W_2 $ be two subspaces of $V$ , such that $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$. Let  $P_{W_1},P_{W_2} $ be the orthogonal projection on $W_1$ and $W_2$.

My first question, does it means that $P_{W_1}P_{W_2} = 0 $? I think so because, let $v \in  V$ so $P_{W_2}(v) = v $ with only $W_2$ component. So $P_{W_1}P_{W_2}(v) = 0 $ cause $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\} $ , am I right?

which means , $P_{W_1}P_{W_2}= P_{W_2}P_{W_1} = 0$ ?

Now I want to prove that   $P_{W_1}P_{W_2} = P_{W_2}P_{W_1} \iff  W_1\bot W_2$.

What I tried:

$$P_{W_1}P_{W_2} = 0 \iff W_2 \subseteq  \ker (P_{W_1})$$
and $\operatorname{im}(P_{W_2}) = W_2 $ something I proved, and $\ker (P_{W_1}) = W_1^\perp$  which means $ W_1 \perp W_2$

If all that I tried is right, why they gave me in the question the data - $P_{W_1}P_{W_2} = P_{W_2}P_{W_1}$ I didn't use it in my proof, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you are right (but try to use a better notation to make things clearer), and the term I think you want is "$\;W_1,\,W_2\;$ are orthogonal", written $\;W_1\perp W_2\;$ .

Comment: thanks i changed, but do you understand why the gave me the data  $Pw1Pw2 = Pw2Pw1$ ?

Comment: How did you prove that $\;\text{Im} P_2=W_2\;$ ? Also, what you proved at the end of your calculations is that $\;W_2\subset W_1^\perp\;$.  You also need the other way around...

Comment: $\;W_2\subset W_1^\perp\;$ $\iff \forall  w_2 \in W_2$ $ w_2 \in W_1^\perp$
$\iff \forall w_2 \in W_2 $  $ \forall w_1 \in W_1$  $<w_2,w_1> = 0 $

Comment: You only proved that $P_{W_1}P_{W_2}(v)=0$ when $v\in W_2$. In general this need not be true for all $v\in V$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. why this isnt true for all $v$? take some $v$ , $P_{W_2} (v)  = v_{W_2} $ which is v by only the componnet of $W_2$

Comment: @moshe Yes: $\;W_2\subset W_1^\perp\;$ means that $\;\langle w_2,w_1\rangle=0\;$ , **for all** $\;w_i\in W_i\;$ ...but this **does not mean** that $\;W_2\;$ is **all of** $\;W_1^\perp\;$ ...! Meaning: there could be some $\;z\in W_1^\perp\setminus W_2\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio but i do not need to prove that $W_1^\perp = W_2$ 
just prove $W_1 \perp W_2$ which means $\forall w_1 \in W_1 , w_2 \in W_2 <w_1,w_2> = 0 $ that what i proved, or i miss something? thanks for the help

Comment: @moshe Oh, I see... Then I think you're right.

Comment: @DonAntonio i stiil dont understand why the gave me the data,  maybie what Arnaud D. said is true, so all the prove is wrong ... 
Thanks for your help

Comment: @moshe If you write $P_{W_2}(v)=v_{W_2}$, how do you find $P_{W_1}(v_{W_2})=0$? (By the way, I hope my edit didn't change the meaning of your post. Don't hesitate to re-edit if that's the case.)

Comment: @ArnaudD because $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\}$ $P_{W_1}(v) = v_{W_1}$ so if $v \in W_2$ then its $0$

Comment: @ArnaudD. didnt tag before~ , if my prove wrong, i cant understand why

Comment: @ArnaudD. what is $W_2$? and what is v?

Comment: @moshe How about the following counterexample : take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $W_1=\mathbb{R}(1,0)$ and $W_2=\mathbb{R}(1,1)$. Then $W_1\cap W_2$ is trivial, but $P_{W_1}P_{W_2}(2,4)=P_{W_1}(3,3)=(3,0)$ but $P_{W_2}P_{W_1}(2,4)=P_{W_2}(2,0)=(1,1)$. So the composites are different from one another and different from $0$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks! , you told me above that i proved only when $v \in W_2$ but if i take the same $W_2 and W_1$ in your counterexample , and $v = (3,3)$ then $P_{W_2}(v) = (3,3)$ and then $P_{W_1}(3,3) = (3,0)$
so it doesnt right with $v \in W_2$ ?

Comment: You need the condition because your initial conjecture is false: in general, $P_{W_1}P_{W_2}\ne0$. As a counterexample, let $W_1$ be the span of $(1,1)^T$ and $W_2$ the span of $(1,0)^T$. Since $P_{W_1}(1,0)^T=\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)^T\ne0$, you can immediately conclude that $P_{W_1}P_{W_2}\ne0$.